# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jogl

I followed this tutorial: http://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/tutorial-faster-rendering-with-vertex-buffer-objects/
When I try to start my application, I'm getting a

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
```

Error.
Can anyone help me?
Teddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries are usually prefaced with "lib", thus the file you are looking for  should be called "libgluegen-rt.so".  It must be located somewhere in /usr folder . Since you are using eclipse you can select the Build-Path Configuration Menu, go to Libraries, then under JRE System Library, add  the path where your .so file is present

Answer (score 0):

it is due to it's not ghetting the methods from the library try to connect properly the librarys in eclipse buildpath.if it is not working may be there is some problem in the eclipse try to run it in different version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu, the following may help

```
sudo apt-get install libjogl-java libjogl-jni libgluegen2-rt-java libgluegen2-build-java libgluegen
```