# How to execute project with JOGL library?

Tags: java, jogl

I'm developing Java project with JOGL, but when I'm trying to execute my project I'll got the following message:

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: E:\Eclipse\Projects\FuzzyProject\lib\jogl2-rc10\gluegen-natives-windows-i586.jar (Can't find file), while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of jar:file:/E:/Eclipse/Projects/FuzzyProject/lib/jogl2-rc10/gluegen-natives-windows-i586.jar!/ (file:/E:/Eclipse/Projects/FuzzyProject/lib/jogl2-rc10/ + gluegen-natives-windows-i586.jar)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From console    `java  -Djava.library.path=<path to native library> -jar (if jar) <name of jar or class>`

From code just `System.loadLibrary(<path to native library>)`

From Eclipse: `Run Configuration -> Arguments -> VM Argiments->-Djava.library.path=<path to native library>`

Comment: Which native library do yo mean?

Comment: @ДенисНагибин gluegen-rt.jar ?

Comment: I have tried "System.loadLibrary("lib/jogl2-rc10/gluegen-rt.jar");" but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: @ДенисНагибин Are you sure that path is correct ? Try to use Eclipse config and put full path. And check your libraries, have you added gluegen-rt to classpath ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running this from eclipse and on a windows machine, so have a look here: [I installed JOGL but why wont Eclipse recognize my hello world program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334203/i-installed-jogl-but-why-wont-eclipse-recognize-my-hello-world-program)

For gluegen, have a look here: [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path RCP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453506/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-gluegen-rt-in-java-library-path-rcp-applicati)